# NullPointerException in j.u.Scanner usage

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, jframe

I am trying to use a scanner to edit the level of my tower defense game. However it will not update the level (the tile images) to that of the custom file (0 is grass 1 is stone -1 is nothing, etc.). I have found the error but how do i fix it, what do i need to add/change to get rid of this? I solved the first error but now i get this:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Levels.loadLevels(Levels.java:13)
    at Window.define(Window.java:28)
    at Window.paintComponent(Window.java:44)
```

line 13: `Window.room.block[y][x].groundID = loadLevelsScanner.nextInt();`
line 28: `levels.loadLevels(new File("levels/level1.level"));`
line 44: `define();`

This is the scanner file:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Levels {
    public void loadLevels(File loadPath) {
        try {
            Scanner loadLevelsScanner = new Scanner(loadPath);

            while(loadLevelsScanner.hasNext()) {

                for(int y=0;y<Window.room.block.length;y++) {
                    for(int x=0;x<Window.room.block[0].length;x++) {
                        Window.room.block[y][x].groundID = loadLevelsScanner.nextInt();
                    }
                }

                for(int y=0;y<Window.room.block.length;y++) {
                    for(int x=0;x<Window.room.block[0].length;x++) {
                        Window.room.block[y][x].airID = loadLevelsScanner.nextInt();
                    }
                }

            }

            loadLevelsScanner.close();

        } catch(Exception e) {

        }
    }
}
```

this is the window file:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Window extends JPanel implements Runnable {

    public Thread thread = new Thread(this);

    public static Image[] tileset_ground = new Image[100];
    public static Image[] tileset_air = new Image[100];

    public static int myWidth, myHeight;

    public static boolean isFirst = true;

    public static Room room;
    public static Levels levels;

    public Window() {
        thread.start();
    }

    public void define() {
        room = new Room();
        levels = new Levels();

        levels.loadLevels(new File("levels/level1.level"));

        for(int i=0;i<tileset_ground.length; i++) {
            tileset_ground[i] = new ImageIcon("resources/tileset_ground.png").getImage();
            tileset_ground[i] = createImage(new FilteredImageSource(tileset_ground[i].getSource(), new CropImageFilter(0, 32 * i, 32, 32)));
        }

        for(int i=0;i<tileset_air.length; i++) {
            tileset_air[i] = new ImageIcon("resources/tileset_air.png").getImage();
            tileset_air[i] = createImage(new FilteredImageSource(tileset_air[i].getSource(), new CropImageFilter(0, 32 * i, 32, 32)));
        }

    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        if(isFirst) {
            define();

            isFirst = false;
        }

        g.clearRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

        room.draw(g);
    }

    public void run() { 
        while(true) {

            if(!isFirst) {
                room.physic();
            }

            repaint();

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1);
            } catch(Exception e) {

            }

        }

    }

}
```

This is the room file:

```
import java.awt.*;

public class Room {
    public int worldWidth = 40;
    public int worldHeight = 20;
    public int blockSize = 32;

    public Block[][] block;

    public Room() {
        block = new Block[worldHeight][worldWidth];
    }

    public void define() {

    }


    public void physic() {

    }   

    public void draw(Graphics g) {

        for(int y=0;y<block.length;y++) {
            for(int x=0;x<block[0].length;x++) {
                block[y][x] = new Block(x * blockSize, y * blockSize, blockSize, blockSize, Value.groundGrass, Value.airAir);
                block[y][x].draw(g);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

this is the block file:

```
import java.awt.*;

public class Block extends Rectangle {
    public int groundID;
    public int airID;

    public Block(int x, int y, int width, int height, int groundID, int airID) {
        setBounds(x, y, width, height);

        this.groundID = groundID;
        this.airID = airID;
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(Window.tileset_ground[groundID], x, y, width, height, null);

        if(airID != Value.airAir) {
            g.drawImage(Window.tileset_air[airID], x, y, width, height, null);
        }

    }

}
```

And lastly this is the custom file the scanner is supposed to read:

```
1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0

-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
```

Comment: i closed that one because it wasn't about the original issue anymore

Comment: It's exactly the same issue. You just copied the whole content, except the headline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the error message:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Levels.loadLevels(Levels.java:11)
```

Line 11 of Levels.java is

```
for(int y=0;y<Window.room.block.length;y++) {
```

So, either `Window.room` is null, or `Window.room.block` is null.

Comment: Window.room.block is null but i don't know how to fix it

Comment: Initialize it in the constructor rather than initialize it (again and again and again) in the `draw()` method.

Comment: Copy the code you have in the draw() method, paste it inside the Room constructor, then remove the line `block[y][x].draw(g);` from the constructor. In the draw() method, remove the lines `block = new Block[worldHeight][worldWidth];` and the line `block[y][x] = new Block(x * blockSize, y * blockSize, blockSize, blockSize, Value.groundGrass, Value.airAir);`. If you don't know what a constructor is, you're not ready to do swing programming, which is HARD!

Comment: Thanks so much, that was what i tried to do earlier with the define method but it never worked.

P.S. now i know what a constructor is

Comment: NOW you know what a constructor is?? WTF? Dude you need to grab a proper book sit down and read a bit before jumping in head first!

Comment: I did some research after you mentioned it

Answer (score 2):

You have *not* instantiated `Room`, this part is causing the `NPE`: `Window.room`. Two things to be aware of:

1. It's a bad idea to have all your attributes as `static` members
2. You need to instantiate all the (`static` or instance) attributes somewhere *before* the first use

In your code, you need to make sure that the `define()` method in `Window` is called before the `loadLevels()` method in `Levels`.

Comment: how do i do this though, i'm new to java?